# QGIS Python all_simple_paths

Tags: qgis, python, networkx

I have my shapefile imported as shown below:

[image]

I calculate all **all_simple_paths** from root to all leaf nodes of a graph.
Red dot is a node to start with. It gives me all path from red dot to green dot.
But **all_simple_paths** do not return paths from node red dot to other leaves (in black). It comes blank.

Each line has start and end point geometry linestring.
Is there any condition in **networkx** to return all paths?

Code is as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_shp(str(iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer().source()))
paths = [] 
for node in (x for x in G.nodes()):
  for leaf in (x for x in G.nodes_iter() if G.out_degree(x)==0):
    print node 
    print leaf
    paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, node, leaf))
    print paths
```